# Ternary operator with narrowing concept

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Why the following statements show an error while compiling

```
 int a=10,b=20;   
   byte c=(a<b)?40:50;
   System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: if you remove the type `byte` it will compile. `b` is already declared within the enclosing scope.

Comment: int a=10,b=20; byte c=(a<b)?40:50; System.out.println(c);

Comment: What happens now

Comment: As per your update, the code is not compiling because the default type of an integral number is a type `int` rather you can cast it to a `byte` to remove the compilation error like so -->  `byte c=(a<b)?(byte)40:50;`. this is called _narrowing_ the type and you could lose data.

Comment: Is it correct to cast the whole            byte c=(byte(a<b)?40:50);

Comment: no, that will not compile, the parenthesis should surround the type `byte`. you can either do as I've suggested in my previous comment or the one suggested within the provided answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b is already declared.

You can try

```
int a=10,b=20;   
byte c=(byte) ((a<b)?40:50);
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: If you make any variable as final, you cannot change the value of final variable. So, no need cast to byte. You can try: byte c=(10<20)?40:50;